# Accent mark problems in CLion

Tags: c, encoding, utf-8, clion, diacritics

I'm having an issue when coding in C with CLion IDE (2021.1.1 on Windows 10) trying to show accent marks in console. Concretely, the program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Rectángulo");
    return 0;
}
```

shows in console

```
Rect├íngulo
```

I suspect it is a problem related with encoding settings. I have used the following encoding settings in CLion:

- Settings + Editor + File Encodings: UTF-8 both in Global Encoding and Project Encoding
- Settings + Editor + General + Console: UTF-8 in Default Encoding

I have tried with several combinations of file and console encoding settings but I have found no solution to show the correct 'á' character on console.

Thanks for the support.

Comment: Try calling `setlocale(LC_ALL, "")` at the beginning of your program. Make sure your locale is a UTF-8 one.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've tried including setlocale(LC_ALL,"") before the printf statement, but it still doesn't works.

Comment: I don't know how `á` can become `├í`. Can you run `od -c your-program-source.c` and locate the line that has the `á`? Can you do the same with the program output?

Comment: I suspect it is a problem related with encoding settings. I'm using Windows 10 and it doesn't seem to accept the "od" command.

Comment: Oh sorry I've missed that, thought it was a Mac for some reason. On Windows UTF-8 in the console is a problem. You probably need to use wide characters and UTF-16.

Comment: Before switching to UTF-16 and wchar_t, try running your program in the new Windows Terminal (not the cmd console) https://akr.am/blog/posts/using-utf-8-in-the-windows-terminal. Are you using gcc, clang or Microsoft toolchain? If the latter, verify that your source file encoding is UTF-8 *with BOM*, and that you are passing /utf-8 flag to the compiler.

Comment: I've finally solved the problem changing the codepage encoding in Windows Registry: setting in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage the key OEMCP=65001 (that is, UTF-8) and rebooting the system. After that, the refered setting for the encoding in CLion IDE works, and the accent marks appear correctly in the console integrated in the IDE. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I've finally solved the problem changing the codepage encoding in Windows Registry.

That is, in registry, I went to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage, set OEMCP=65001 (that is, UTF-8) and rebooted the system.

After that, the above settings for the encoding in CLion IDE worked well and the accent marks were shown correctly in the console integrated in the IDE.